# Will LibGDX supports 3D like Unity3D

Tags: android, libgdx, game-development

Can anyone please tell me that will  libgdx supports 3D like Unity3D and please tell me some games which are built on libgdx 3d if possible.

Comment: While it's primarily for 2D games, LibGDX also knows 3D as per http://blog.xoppa.com/basic-3d-using-libgdx-2/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your question is pretty general, but the libGDX 3D API is pretty stable, easy to use and has many features.

It can not only render basic 3D shapes like spheres and boxes, but also load complex models via .obj or .fbx files. It supports animations, normal and specular maps, a basic lighting system with point lights and directional lights. The latest version also added a high-performance 3D particle engine, including an editor to create those effects.

Furthermore it supports bullet physics which is a 3D physics engine which works pretty well with the 3D API of libGDX.

I'm currently developing a 3D game myself and I can only say that everything works really nicely. The performance is great and with my old laptop I can render several million textured tris with lighting at 60FPS. One example of an already published cross platform 3D game made with libGDX is [Delver](http://www.delvergame.com/) (its graphics are very simplistic though and do not show the capabilities of libGDX that well).

Comment: First link: 404 Not Found